# Angular 6 nested sub child reactive Form not reset

Tags: angular, forms, components, reset, children

I have a two level nested FormGroup.

I pass by @Input an FormGroup to the first child component network `myForm.get('network')`.

Inside the component network i pass by @Input a sub FormGroup `network?.get('proxy')` in another component (proxy component).

[code stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rz6fgk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnetwork.component.ts)

**Sample**:

```
this.myForm = fb.group({ 
     id: [null],
     network: fb.group({
       status: [true],
       proxy: fb.group({ enable: [true] })
     })
  })
```

**Summary**:

Parent component => myForm

child network component => `myForm.get('network')` ngOnChanges trigger

sub child proxy component => `myForm.get('network')`ngOnChanges **not** trigger

ps: i use on each child the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

**Probleme**:

But i seems when i reset from my parent (myForm) `myForm.reset()`, he reset just one sub level in network component, but not in the proxy sub child component.

How i could chain this reset from the root tho the sub child ?

I tried pass the formGroup in a observale and async the result, but to complex use it in my all structure.

**My idee is**:

Call From Network the child proxy with `@ViewChild` and reset from there but look that weird for me.

Is a better solution ?

Comment: Your stackblitz link only shows the result, can we try and edit it ? Like sending the editable stackblitz of what you have created and we'll try to edit it on our end to see what's the problem

Comment: @KShewengger for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rz6fgk

Comment: sorry edited my link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're not getting the reset on the child components due to** [ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy).

There are two ways of updating the children forms:

1. Manually calling `markForCheck()` (emit children a reset has just happened through a Subject/Observable combo)
2. Updating the @Input of each children on `reset()`

Because of the two nested components, I suggest to take option 1 and let the children be responsible to reflect the changes.

**Here is a working example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pskaws

Comment: Can't markForCheck the form, because my value is just set by the @Input decorator throught the child's. Solution 2 should be great but don't know what is better, remove the OnPush on child or  push a subject in parent throught child's.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on your parent component `(AppComponent)` not on its children as when you put it on your children, you are telling the parent that any changes exists from it **(parent)** must not mutate on them **(children**). This happens when its data/form is dependent from another component. If it's independent, you can safely put **OnPush ChangeDetection** to make any from your active data to be immutable.

In your case, you are just borrowing the original data from the parent. So when you declare OnPush on your children, it will set the current fetched @childForm as their own and make it Immutable and will not be changed from any events/emitted unless action shall be performed inside its child component.